# Start trailhead with specific modules from sandbox for user training

Tags: sandbox, trailhead, training

I´d like to set specific modules for final users, I´m going to give a training session about a new implementation in SF. For many users it´s the first time they use Salesforce even for some of they, the first time they work with leads and opportunities. So I want to ask that users take some basic modules before attending the training session. 
For the training we´re going to use a sandbox org but I want to know if there si a possibility to launch the trailhead from this sandbox and that the users only can see the specific modules. All of this without having to create a trailhead account. Also I want to track their progress.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't track their progress without a trailhead account. They can simply use their login credentials for production to log in, and you can install the [Trailhead Tracker](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EFpAtUAL) to get information on who has done what. You can't specifically *restrict* them to *just* the modules you want, but you could set up a [Trailmix](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/trailmixes) for them to follow. Or, if you really wanted to, you could go as far as [myTrailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/mytrailhead) to build your own internal modules and use those instead.

Comment: Thanks.  I´m going to try with Trailhead Tracker.